# Can I Make Content Appear Within a Div; When a Separate Div is Hovered Over With The Cursor?

Tags: javascript, html, image, tags, title

I am creating a website and have some Div tags that contain pictures. I also have a Content Div that serves to give description for each image.

However, when an picture is selected (like a roll over image). I would like for the Content Div to display the description for the relevant image.

Can you help me guys?

Comment: Semantically you should use the `title` attribute the `alt` means alternative, which should been displayed in case of an loading error or an plain text browser.

Comment: Can you show us some code or a more detailed explanation of what you want to achieve?

Comment: If I understand the question, this would not be css. Could be done using either jQuery, JavaScript etc..

Comment: @Pmleader, sorry dude, I should have posted my code. I have resolved the issue now though. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using jQuery event handlers, you can accomplish what you need using the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events:

```
$("#image").on("mouseenter",function()
{
    $("#content").html("<your description goes here>");
});

$("#image").on("mouseleave",function()
{
    $("#content").html("");
});
```

Check out this JSFiddle that shows the above code in action:

http://jsfiddle.net/1u3u050o/

Also, I suggest you read up more on jQuery if you're not familiar. It's a JavaScript library that does a lot of the heavy lifting for you for situations like this.

Answer (score 2):

You can grab the value of a HTML attribute using the `:before` or `:after` pseudo elemnents `content` property.

Unfortunately the `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements can't be used with `img` tags so you would have to use a parent element.

Here is one way:

```css
.wrap {
    position: relative;
}
.wrap:before {
    content: attr(title);
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    color:#fff;
    z-index: 1;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

.wrap:hover:before {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap" title="Some title text"><img src="http://placehold.it/400x150"></div>
```

Comment: Nothing will work for _all_ browser versions. This will work for IE8 and above I believe

Comment: Fine just wanted to know. Nice answer. +1 for using CSS